# Getting files in hidden folder?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I would like to get files from a hidden folder

```
C:\Users\XXX\AppData
```

and my code in my Windows UWP application is below:

```
var folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

StorageFolder folder = await folderPicket.PickSingleFolderAsync();

if (folder != null) {
   StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedFolderToken", folder);
   var allFilesFolders = await folder.GetItemsAsync(); // exception is thrown
}
```

When i run the code above, `ArgumentException was unhandled by user code` is thrown, may I know how can I obtain the files in hidden folders?

This behaviour is true, if I try to list the files inside any hidden folder.

Comment: I guess this may be 'by design'. Similarly you cannot get hidden file.